# How to use a 'for loop' in place of a 'while loop'

Tags: java

Had to write the following program for an on line pre java class using, while, do-while and for loops.
Looking for a little explanation.  Thanks in advance!
PS While looking for reference books is this Java or Javascript?  Any suggestions for a good reference book?  I get the concept, mostly, the devil is certainly in the details.

```
public class ExamsFor {

    public static void main(String[] arguments) {


    int inputNumber; // One of the exams input by the user.
    int sum;     // The sum of the exams.
    int count;   // Number of exams.
    Double Avg;    // The average of the exams.


    /* Initialize the summation and counting variables. */

    sum = 0;
    count = 0;

    /* Read and process the user's input. */

    TextIO.put("Please enter the first exam: "); // get the first exam.


        inputNumber = TextIO.getlnInt();

    for (inputNumber!=0; sum += inputNubmer; count++ ) {  // had the while loop below enter here, worked

    TextIO.put("Please enter the next exam, or 0 to end: "); // get the next exam.  
    inputNumber = TextIO.getlnInt();
    } 

    /* Display the result. */

    if (count == 0) {
    TextIO.putln("You didn't enter any data!");
    }
    else {
    Avg = ((double)sum) / count;
    TextIO.putln();
    TextIO.putln("You entered " + count + " exams.");
    TextIO.putf("The average for the exams entered is %1.2f.\n", Avg);
    } 

    } // end main ()
}  // end class ExamsFor

/*  Had the following 'while loop' in place of the 'for loop'


while (inputNumber != 0) {
    sum += inputNumber;  // Add inputNumber to running sum.
    count ++;        // Count the input by adding 1 to the count.

*/
```

Comment: For the clarification, this is Java, not Javascript.

What exactly is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't your for loop be: (note the preceding ; and a typo in sum+=inputNumber)

```
for (;inputNumber!=0; sum += inputNumber, count++ )
```

The while loop would be

```
while(inputNumber!=0) {
// rest of the things
 sum+=inputNumber;
 count++;
}
```

Comment: That did it! I know there are many ways to accomplish any given tasks but I don't know that I would have ever figured that out.  I'm a network guy just trying to survive this class.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 5):

You can compare both `for` and `while` statement observing that you mainly need 4 things in an iterative construct:

- the initial value of the value used in the condition (`A`)
- a condition that is used to check if keeping up iterations (`B`)
- a statement that modifies the value that is checked every time (`C`)
- the body of the statement itself (`BODY`)

for `for` you have

```
for (A; B; C)
  BODY
```

while for `while` (full of word jokes here :) you have something like

```
A;
while (B)
{
  BODY;
  C;
}
```

That's quite simple, isn't it?

Comment: To be more precise, BODY should be in a `try` block and C should be in a `finally` block in case body has some `continue` statements.

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_syntax#for_loop) and compare your for loop to the expected syntax to see where you're going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your `for` loop which is basically incorrect. From The Java Tutorials:

> ### [The for Statement](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)
>
> [...] The general form of the for statement
>   can be expressed as follows:
>
> ```
> for (initialization; termination; increment) {
>     statement(s)
> }
> ```
>
> When using this version of the for
>   statement, keep in mind that:
>
> - The initialization expression initializes the loop; it's executed
>     once, as the loop begins.
> - When the termination expression evaluates to false, the loop
>     terminates.
> - The increment expression is invoked after each iteration through the loop;
>     it is perfectly acceptable for this
>     expression to increment or decrement a
>     value.
>
> The following program, `ForDemo`, uses
>   the general form of the for statement
>   to print the numbers 1 through 10 to
>   standard output:
>
> ```
> class ForDemo {
>      public static void main(String[] args) {
>           for(int i=1; i<11; i++){
>                System.out.println("Count is: " + i);
>           }
>      }
> }
> ```

I suggest to start with the Tutorials but if you're interested, you'll find complete and more formal details in the Java Language Specification, section [14.14 The for Statement](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.14).