# Java Changing For to While

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I would like to change this for loop to a while statement:

```
for (int x = 0; x < items.size(); x++) {...}
```

I've tried:

```
int x = 0;
while(x<items.size()){
x++;
...
}
```

but it won't work.

Comment: Why it won't work? Can you give more details?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221132/how-to-use-a-for-loop-in-place-of-a-while-loop

Answer (score 7):

put the x++ at the end of the while block.

```
while(x<items.size()){
...
x++;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It should be

```
int x = 0;
while(x<items.size()){
...

x++;
}
```

With the x++ in the end of the loop (because in the for loop, the increment section is executed only after the program control reaches the closing braces), but otherwise everything looks ok. It should work.

Answer (score 2):

Your code should have been as follows,

```
int x = 0;
while(x<items.size()){
...
...
...
x++;
}
```

The reason for `x++` operation to be the last statement in the loop is to increment the value of 'x' only when we are done with the loop and we need to increment the value of looping variable.

If you put `x++` in the starting of looping code, the code will not work for the last looping scheme, wherein, prior to entering the loop,  the value of x would have been  `x=items.Size( );`. So it wouldn't be able to enter the loop as the condition is `x<items.Size();`